# Broadcast Receiver issue, register a Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I  have a problem with a Broadcast Receiver

I want to execute a Broadcast Receiver after a wifi scan, if i register de broadcast receiver in this wait, it works, but only when the app is running:

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
```

i want to register de Broadcast Receiver in the Android Manifest, like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".WiFiScanReceiver"  android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION"/>
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

but this way, it isn't works, please help me!

Comment: what your android SDK or API use in application.

Answer (score 1):

The string representation of `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE` is `android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS`, as is indicated in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION). That is not what you have in your `<action>` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<receiver android:name="com.madhu.wifitest.WiFiScanReceiver" android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS"></action>
</intent-filter>


 /*add these permissions in the manifest*/
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```